# how to make right button in navigation bar using react-native-router-flux?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am tring to make right button on navigation bar using react-native-router-flux.

My code is

```
import React from 'React';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Scene, Router, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
...
const filterIcon = () => (
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>} style={{...}}>
<Icon name="filter" size={30}/>
</TouchableHighlight>
);
const MainRounter=()=>(
<Router>
<Scene
key="main"
component={mainPage}
initial={true}
renderRightButton={()=>filterIcon}
/>
</Router>
);
```

But I can't show right button on navigation bar.
How can I make it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `onRight`, `rightTitle` or `rightButtonImage` to add the right button to the navBar.

```js
const MainRounter = return (
    <Router>
        <Scene
            key="main"
            component={mainPage}
            initial={true}
            onRight={ ()=> whatever you want to do }
            rightButtonImage={require('path/to/your/icon')}
        />
    </Router>
);
```

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Thank you.
But I want one more image button in right side, at least 2.
And onRight={Actions.scene1key}
But switching scene1 is failed. Could you explain why this is happened?

Comment: Ahh I see, you want more than one right button. Unfortunately I don't have an answer for that, and you should do this to switch scenes `onRight={() => Actions.scene1Key()}`

Comment: How to add One more icons or title

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE - 18 Oct 2017**

With the last releases the methods described below have stopped working, again. So, my last solution for this is:

```
class MyAwesomeClass extends React.Component {


   componentWillMount() {
        Actions.refresh({ right: this._renderRightButton });
   }

   _renderRightButton = () => {
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._handleIconTouch() } >
                <Icon name="check" size={26} color='grey' />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };

    _handleIconTouch = () => {
        console.log('Touched!');
    }

}
```

**UPDATE - 07 Aug 2017**

As RNRF4 uses now ReactNavigation as navigation solution, the above solution stopped working. To make it work again I using the ReactNavigation API directly. This is my solution:

```
class MyAwesomeClass extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        headerRight: <TouchableIcon size={22} name="search" onPress={() =>    
                        navigation.state.params.handleIconTouch()} />,
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleIconTouch: 
              this.handleIconTouch });

    }

    handleIconTouch = () => {
        console.log('Touched!');
    }

}
```

In navigationOptions the general navigation info is accesed in a class-level. As the context is static its impossible to access our Component methods and their params. To make it work a little workaround is needed.

So, first you need to define the function which will handle your touch, in this case handleIconTouch. In here you should define the action your button will perform when it's pressed. As this function is not static you can access props and state from here which gives you more functionality and options.

Then, in your *componentWillMount()* method, add the method to the navigation params with *setParams()* to be available in the static context of navigationOptions. As this method is not static either, you can pass any required params to your button here.

And finally, using the params, define your button inside navigationOptions/headerRight key using the component that suits you the most.

**ORIGINAL**
I recommend  you this approach:

1. Create a method with your desired logic and images, for example:

   ```
   renderRightButton = () => {
       return(
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => null } >
               <Icon name="check" size={26} color='grey' />
           </TouchableOpacity>
       );
   };
   ```
2. In your componentWillMount() method add at the beginning:

   `Actions.refresh({ renderRightButton: this.renderRightButton });`
3. Ready to go!

Tell me if you have any doubts.

Comment: This not woking. RNRF4 nothing appear. 

   import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
   ...

  componentWillMount() {
    Actions.refresh({ renderRightButton: this.renderRightButton });
  }

  renderRightButton = () => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => null} >
      <Text>Click Me!</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

Comment: updated, try with this solution now and comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: post a question with your code and put the link here, I will try to take a look.

Answer (score 4):

For RNRF4. Thank you [Jacse](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/145).

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';

class MyScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
      return {
        headerRight: <Button title="Save" onPress={() => params.handleSave()} />
      };
    };

    _saveDetails() {
      Alert.alert('clicked save');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSave: this._saveDetails });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View />
      );
    }
}
export default MyScreen;
```

Comment: You should not do this with RNRF4 as you are bypassing RNRF by using react-navigation api  see here https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2282

Answer (score 4):

RNRF4 I tried this code working fine

```
   <Scene 
         key="SignUp" 
         component={SignUp} 
         title="SignUp"
         onRight={()=>{}} 
         rightTitle={' Save'} />
```

//SignUp Component

```
export default class SignUp extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
            'onRight': this.handleIconTouch
        })
    }

    handleIconTouch() {
        debugger;
    }

    render() {
        return ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 2021:**

This will remove the deprecation warning.

```
HomePage.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    headerRight: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Create')}>
        <Feather name="plus" size={30} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )  };
};
```

Here `Feather` is a library to show icons in the application, it is available in Expo.

You can use this library by importing it like below.

```
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a custom navBar take a look at this issue in github [custom navBar](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/885)